# Groovy Compiler 1.7 - how to install it? eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, groovy

vvSo hi guys, im tryin to install groovy 1.7 plugin to my eclipse indigo but i can't..

I followed instructions on  [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse) but unfortunetly it doesn't work.

What i mean by doesn't work?
Even without installing 2.0 compiler i have it

> After installing Groovy-Eclipse without the extra compilers, the Groovy 1.8 compiler is active by default.  And the Groovy 2.0 compiler becomes active after installing the extra compiler.

And as it says i shouldn't have but well meaby its an old description.
Then i'm goin to *Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler*  page, and guess what i can only switch to *1.8.6.xx-MORENUMBERS-e37-REALEASE*. When i do i only can switch back to *2.0.7.xx-MORENUMBERS-e37-REALEASE*.

So where is this 1.7 compiler because i dont see it there?

So i followed up with adding to *eclipse.ini* -groovy.compiler.level 17, still doesn't work.

I tried to change file *bundles.info*, but there is no 1.7 version.

So someone know how i can get this compiler 1.7? I was searching it so long, and i only found Groovy Eclipse plugin that only operates on 2 version (above one).

Thanks in advance for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since i last saw 1.7 in the plugin. I guess it got outdated and removed. [This page](http://static.springsource.org/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html) (near the bottom) tells that Groovy 1.7 is deprecated for GGTS (which, i guess, uses Groovy-eclipse):

> Deprecating of Groovy 1.7 support
>
> The Groovy 1.7 support in GGTS has been deprecated. It is still possible to install it for this release, but it will be removed in future releases. If you need to install the Groovy 1.7 compiler, then:
>
> Go to Help -> Install new software
>      Choose the Springsource update site to work with
>      Uncheck Group items by category, As shown in the image:

Is that doesn't work, maybe you can try to install an older version of Groovy-eclipse from http://dist.springsource.org/.

Comment: Above advice in July 2019+ appears to only show Groovy 2+ options under Help. So manually getting the 1.7 from the dist url -  Under linux both STS / GGTS appeared to behave oddly if I added 1.7 then in options set Groovy compiler to be 1.7 for entire work space both create new grails project  and  in main project groovy segment appeared to go missing after restart - I have found not touching main window  properties then groovy compiler alone and on specific project right click properties and set compiler to be 1.7 gets around the options going missing.