# Groovy compiler 1.7 to 1.8 GGTS

Tags: grails, compiler-construction, groovy

I saw from here [Groovy Compiler 1.7 - how to install it? eclipse indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661937/groovy-compiler-1-7-how-to-install-it-eclipse-indigo) that Groovy 1.7 support in GGTS has been deprecated.

does anyone knows the impacts/changes of switching from groovy compiler 1.7 to 1.8 in the latest GGTS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a formal document listing incompatible changes between 1.7 and 1.8. Best try for yourself, and make sure to recompile all Groovy code against 1.8.